# How can I create a diamond using <svg> element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to create a diamond using `<svg>` and `<polygon>` HTML5 elements. I specified the points, but it is not being filled as a diamond; instead it is being filled as a pair of triangles. Here's my approach:

```html
<div>
    <svg width="2000" height="2000">
    <polygon points="25 25, 75 25, 50 50, 50 0" style=" fill: blue; stroke:black;"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of making your own svgs, you might want to check out the searchable library of bootstrap icons. they have several different free to use diamond icon svgs. https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: invert the middle pairs of coordinates.

Comment: Take a piece of paper; mark the top-left 0,0 Then plot the 4 coordinates in your polyline and draw the lines between them. That way you learn what you are doing wrong, instead of copy/pasting code from others

Comment: `width="2000" height="2000" `?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you enjoy

```html
<svg width="2000" height="2000">
  <polygon points="0 40,40 80,80 40,40 0" style=" fill: blue; stroke:black;"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mr dqhendricks said in the comments above it would be better if you use the icons in the bootstrap icons library
or you can change your code to

```
<polygon fill="none" stroke-width="3" points="69.445,125 125,28.774 180.556,125 
    125,221.227 " style=" fill: blue; stroke:black;"/>
```

And it will give you a diamond shape